# File Manager create file on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am currently working on a functionality to store files. I am testing the application on an iOS simulator. When I call the File Manager to create a file I get a false response. am I able to save files to the simulator?

code:

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.absoluteString
let response = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
print(response)
```

Comment: You have the oath for the caches directory, but you haven't specified a file in that directory.  You need to append the target file name to the path.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 would I need to add the txt at the end of the path?

Comment: "would I need to add the txt at the end of the path" is an odd question.  It would help if you search and find out why you use file extensions.

Comment: It's up to you; File extensions aren't really needed in this case since iOS doesn't need to find an app to open the file and humans won't see the file.  As long as your app knows what to look for, it doesn't matter what the file name is.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your help! I am indeed adding a file name at the end now and I am still experiencing the same issue. My path looks like this now (its not exactly the same I omitted some folder name or changed them): file:///Users/USERNAME/Library/..../Caches/ApplicationName/some_file

Comment: @ElTomato thank you for your response, I was asking if I needed a file extension due to me having a file name and getting false when trying to create the file.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your help I was able to solve my issue! the problem was I was using absoluteString at the end instead of paths. Filemanager wants just a path not the full url and thus provided an error